# How to extract certain values from a table using the SearchCursor Tool

Tags: python, cursor, arcpy

I konw that similar questions have been asked before but as I am really new to Python I wasnt able to apply other discussions and suggestions made there to my case!

I am trying to write a python script to extract certain values from a table: the table I am referring to is a big collection of nitrate values for different water depths, which are deposited in the columns of the table. As I only need the value of the surface and the deepest point, I want to search through the rows and extract the last value that is not 0. I have started writing a script using the SearchCursor Tool but get stuck at the point, where I want it to search for the first 0-value and then go back and print the value fro mthe column before... Does anyone have an idea how to solve that problem?

```
import arcpy

# Set the Workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:\Teresa\Kerstin\SouthernOcean\03_workspace\Teresa"

# Make table
table = "C:/Users/theidema/Desktop/OxzUti_GridP_Annual.csv"

# Create the search cursor
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(Table)

# Iterate through the rows
row = cursor.next()
while row:
    print (row.getValue(field))
    row = cursor.next()
```

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a visual of what you hope to extract from each field.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, I see three errors.

First, SearchCursor() parameter "Table" is capitalized and your variable "table" isn't.  It is case-sensitive, so they'll need to match.

Secondly, you used "field" as a parameter in your print statement, but it isn't defined.  Above the While loop, define the variable -- something like: field = "NameOfFieldYouWantToSearch"

Finally, also in your While loop, you don't want to redefine your variable "row".  Just make it cursor.next(), removing "row = ".  (Before the loop, row = cursor.next() is meant to be evaluated as True or False, keeping the while loop going so long as there is next row, then when there is no next row it's evaluated as False and the loop terminates.)

Oh yeah!  I noticed your Workspace isn't a File Geodatabase.  I'd work out of a GDB, if I were you.  Especially since Feature Classes can't exist outside GDBs.  If you work with Shapefiles, it might work though.

```
import arcpy

# Set the Workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:\Teresa\Kerstin\SouthernOcean\03_workspace\Teresa" 
#If "Teresa" is a GDB, append ".gdb"

# Define variables
table = "C:/Users/theidema/Desktop/OxzUti_GridP_Annual.csv"
field = "" #Add the Field Name that you want to Search

# Call your CSV in SearchCursor
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(table)

# Iterate through the rows
row = cursor.next()
while row:
    print (row.getValue(field))
    cursor.next()
```